# FB dialog broken (unknown skip_api_login paramenter)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

We're using FB login for a few years now, both from our Mac and Windows app.
Since about a month ago the Windows app stopped connecting to FB, the request to FB just returns with

> skip_api_login=1&error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied

The problem is probably because of the skip_api_login=1 parameter, but the thing is that it wasn't us who added this parameter - It was added by FB.

In Mac everything works fine and we don't have this parameter.

Did FB changed its dialog flow?, or if not, what else could have lead to this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is because your PC client is not handing redirects properly.

Facebook returns this URL when it wants to show the Login screen.   Once the user has logged in, it will return the normal response that you are expecting.

Maybe you remove an event handler during the process?